# How to import a module with "-" in its name in transcrypt?

Tags: transcrypt

I'm writing my first transcrypt code (python transpiled to JS for the browser -- what a great idea!) and I'm stuck already, translating this JS code into python:

```
import { saveAs } from 'file-saver';
import inspect from 'browser-util-inspect';
```

As you can see, both those third-party modules (which are in my `node_modules/` dir, from npm) have hyphens in their name. But it's not legal python to say

```
from node_modules.file-saver import saveAs
```

(because python module names have to be identifiers) so I'm not sure how to proceed.

Answer (score 0):

It should be possible to use module names containing a -, using aliases, but it was broken with TS 3.7.1
It'll be fixed in the next minor release, an example will be included in the autotest.
Sorry for the inconvenience.

[TS 3.7.8](http://www.transcrypt.org) is out, containing a fix for this.

[EDIT]

```
# __pragma__ ('alias', 'specific_module_a', 'specific-module-a')
# __pragma__ ('alias', 'S', '$')
# __pragma__ ('alias', 'test_modules_b', 'test-modules-b')
# __pragma__ ('alias', 'specific_module_b', 'specific-module-b')

from test_modules_a.__specific_module_a import the__S__Function
from test_modules_b__.__specific_module_b import theBFunction as aBFunction

the__S__Variable = 3
print (the__S__Variable)

the__S__Function (print)
aBFunction (print)
```

Note that the pragma's are needed to conform original Python syntax and Python scanner/parser, that don't allow $ and - in names.